# Current users edit and destroy path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to figure out the proper paths for a `current_user` show, edit and destroy links.

This is what i have tried:

```
<% current_user.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.completed %></td>
    <td><%= task.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_current_user_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` in your command line and see what routes are available for your app. Here's some info on [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

If you're using resources, and from the look of it they are nested, then you will need to pass the current_user as well as the task to your show, edit, and destroy paths.

For example, if you have something like this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Then, your `edit_user_task_path` will be `/users/:user_id/tasks/:task_id` (via GET).

Comment: Thanks, Keep getting this error
undefined method `edit_user_task_path'

Comment: Have you tried running `rake routes`? What do you see for your edit task path?

Comment: Seems to be working now, seems to be an error on my path I do apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regular user/task path, there's no reason to make a special route:

```
edit_user_task_path(current_user, task)
```

Comment: Thanks, Keep getting this error
undefined method `edit_user_task_path'

Comment: You were meant to substitute whatever your actual route is called.

Comment: Seems to be working now, seems to be an error on my path I do apologize.